# Having Spring's IoC container instantiate beans with zero config (like Google Guice's behaviour)

Tags: java, spring, guice, spring-ioc

I have a hobby-project which I would like to migrate to Spring.

As an example I have the following classes:

```java
public class OtherBean {
    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println("Message from OtherBean");
    }
}


public class InjectInMe {
    @Inject OtherBean otherBean;

    public void callMethodInOtherBean() {
        otherBean.printMessage();
    }
}
```

However as I read the documentation, I must annotate all classes to be managed by Spring with an annotation like @Component (or others that are similar).

Running it with the following code:

```java
public class SpringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.refresh();

        InjectInMe bean = context.getBean(InjectInMe.class);
        bean.callMethodInOtherBean();
    }
}
```

Gives me the error:

```html
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [somepackage.InjectInMe] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:968)
    at somepackage.SpringTest.main(SpringTest.java:10)
```

My question is: is there a way to make Spring manage any class I ask the ApplicationContext to instantiate **without** me having to register them in an Annotated Config (or XML config)?

In Guice I can just inject into the class

```java
public class GuiceTest {
    static public class GuiceConfig extends AbstractModule {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {}

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceConfig());
        InjectInMe bean = injector.getInstance(InjectInMe.class);
        bean.callMethodInOtherBean();
    }
}
```

Gives me the output:

```html
Message from OtherBean
```

Is there anyway I can make Spring work like Guice? As in make Spring inject my beans **without** me having to register or scan packages for classes annotated with @Component-like annotations?

Any Spring gurus have a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: is there a way to make Spring manage any class I ask
>   the ApplicationContext to instantiate without me having to register
>   them in an Annotated Config (or XML config)?

No, it's not possible. This is simply not how Spring is designed. You must either implicitly (e.g. scan + annotation) or explicitly (e.g. XML bean definition) register your beans.

The least you can do is something like:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
context.register(OtherBean.class);
context.register(InjectInMe.class);
context.refresh();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I debugged Spring's AnnotationConfigApplicationContext and really found no easy way of adding this Guice-like behaviour. I will stick with Guice for the time being as I am not going to register **all** my classes. I hope Spring give us an option in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to provide bean definitions for Spring's `ApplicationContext`:

1. Use component scanning and annotate your types with `@Component` or one of its meta annotations (`@Service`, `@Controller`, etc.)
2. Define a `<bean>` in XML configuration or a `@Bean` in Java configuration (or whatever other type of explicit configuration).
3. Use a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` to register beans directly on a `BeanDefinitionRegistry`.
4. Some `ApplicationContext` subtypes implement `BeanDefinitionRegistry`, so you can register bean definitions with them directly.

The beans generated from these bean definitions will be available when injection is required. You wouldn't want (at least IMO) your container to instantiate a type without you telling it somehow that it is OK.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added bold to the most relevant part of my question

Comment: @discipline Right. That's what I was hinting at with my last sentence. I feel like what Guice is doing is dangerous. You haven't explicitly told it how to get a `OtherBean` instance. You may get very unexpected behavior with how Guice decides to instantiate the type.

Answer (score 0):

You must either declare the class as a @Component, or whatever it may be, or you must provide an xml definition.  If you don't define the bean, how is Spring supposed to know what to do?  For the properties of a class, e.g. MyController has a private service MyService.  If you put the @Autowired tag above the service instantiation, Spring will automatically inject this server into your controller, which is what your comment about @Inject seems to hint at.  However, in order to autowire, you must define a bean for that class, which means you must use either the @Component/@Controller, etc annotation configuration or an xml bean configuration.

Comment: "If you don't define, how is Spring supposed to know what to do?" - Just trying to instantiate it like Google Guice does? Thank you for trying to answer it though.

Comment: By adding the Inject tag, you are adding some sort of annotation, thus    letting Guice know what to do.  The same applies to Spring, but instead of the Inject tag, you use @Autowire

Comment: I added code as an example. Thank you once again for your time. Maybe the question is more clear with the example :-) I would like to know if I can mimic this "Just Works(tm)" behavior of Guice in Spring

Comment: You can add "@Component" right above your OtherBean class declaration, and do the same above your InjectInMe class.  Then, replace the "@Inject" with "@Autowire", and it will just work, provided your applicationContext is configured to accept annotations.

Comment: That's the exact point of my question: how can I dot it **without** @Component-like annotations and **without** registering it in the application context to get the "Just Works (tm)" behavior of Guice?

Comment: Again, the "Just Works" behavior of Guice is caused by the "@Inject" annotation.  If you don't use that extra annotation, Guice will not "Just Work".  With any framework, you must tell it what to do in order for it to work.  With Guice, this is accomplished with the "@Inject" tag.  In Spring, it is accomplished with the annotations.